# Contact form doesn't work, "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: address" MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a contact form and I have no clue on what is going wrong.

This the code for the model I wrote:

```
public class Contact
{
    public string FromName { get; set; } 
    public string FromEmail { get; set; } 
    public string Subject { get; set; } 
    public string Message { get; set; } 
}
```

The controller I created with just read/write actions:

```
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using GJL.Models;

namespace GJL.Controllers
{
    public class ContactController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Contact
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Contact vm)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    MailMessage msz = new MailMessage();
                    msz.From = new MailAddress(vm.FromEmail);//Email which you are getting 
                                                         //from contact us page 
                    msz.To.Add("roykooiman67@gmail.com");//Where mail will be sent 
                    msz.Subject = vm.Subject;
                    msz.Body = vm.Message;
                    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

                    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";

                    smtp.Port = 465;

                    smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential
                    ("roykooiman67@gmail.com", "PasswordGmail");

                    smtp.EnableSsl = true;

                    smtp.Send(msz);

                    ModelState.Clear();
                    ViewBag.Message = "Bedankt voor je bericht!";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ModelState.Clear();
                    ViewBag.Message = $" Er ging iets mis: {ex.Message}";
                }
            }

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Error()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

And my view (in pastebin either it would've been too long):

https://pastebin.com/LvtSzY4V

And this is the error I get:

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: address

I've read that it has to with the credentials. But these are the right credentials for my account.

Comment: Something not clear here. Are you sending to yourself a message from a different address? It seems that you are setting your own credentials but the from address is not yours.

Comment: Sorry if it isnt clear. I'm a beginner in asp.net. I want the message to be recieved on that email address. And the from address is the e-mail the user fills in.

Comment: And you suppose your server is capable to send a message from an unknown (to the server) email while you provide your credentials?

Comment: I really hope, those credentials are fake, or you're in Deep trouble!

Comment: @PoulBak of course the password is a made up one. Not that dumb :)

Comment: @Steve No, that isn't possible. I've followed this tutorial: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1081578/How-to-Implement-Contact-Us-Page-in-ASP-NET-MVC-AS

Comment: @RoyKooiman Put a breakpoint at line `msz.From = new MailAddress(vm.FromEmail);` and check if `vm.FromEamil` has value filled in or is it null?

Comment: @MohsinMehmood i've just tried it, and the value is null

Comment: So now you have a clue what is going on, you're not getting the address the user typed in.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I get that, but still have no clue on how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was fixed after replace `asp-for` attribute with `name` attribute on input controls e.g.

```
    <input name="FromName" class="form-control" />
    <input name="FromEmail" class="form-control" />
    <input name="Subject" class="form-control" />
    <textarea rows="5" cols="15" name="Message" class="form-control"></textarea>
```

asp-for tag helper was introduced in ASP.NET Core MVC and not available in MVC5

Comment: I've tried adding it, but it says it cannot find the type or namespace 'FromBody', Then I did some research and I needed to put in "using System.Web.Http;" at the top of my controller. But since it is restricted to Web API I cant use it here.

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET Core MVC?

Comment: Nope, just MVC5.

Comment: Ok! Can you confirm that  `vm` object is null itself or only `vm.FromEmail` property is null with vm object other properties are populating?

Comment: vm object is not null. Take a look: https://imgur.com/a/sIpeyjy EDIT: also: at the line: 'if (ModelState.IsValid)' the breakpoint says its false.

Comment: Press F12 on the browser to launch developer tools and switch to Network tab and then click the submit button on the email form. You will see a POST request to `contact/Index`. Select that network request and then check the request body parameters passed. Please screenshot if possible

Comment: I did what u said. There is no POST request on that list. Probably because of what I mentioned before I geuss: "at the line: 'if (ModelState.IsValid)' the breakpoint says its false.", Also in the view I have this: @if (ViewBag.Message == null) { WHOLE HTML FORM IS IN HERE }. So what I think happens is that it never reaches that point.

Comment: There must be a POST request as the break point on your controller action code.

Comment: Ahh I see, it says 'OK': "Request URL: http://localhost:59136/contact/index
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: [::1]:59136
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade"